# Click once deployment with local sql database

Tags: vb.net, deployment, clickonce

I have a client application that will be deployed using ClickOnce. The client application will connect to a local sql database on their machine. They will need sql server 2008 express installed upon installed and the .mdf file attached. 
I set Prerequisites to include sql server 2012 express.
So I would like the application when installing to check if sql server already installed with the database. If not then install and attach database.  How can i achieve this properly using click once.  I have a vb.net project using visual studio 2013. any references would help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change your connection string 
to somthing like this
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes

now your sql is linked to a specific database file

check this link https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/